# Using Mapbox Studio (aka Tilemill 2) to create a self-hosted map

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, tilemill-2

What would be the neccessary prerequisites to run a map/tile-server (serving raster tiles) using an exported vector source and tm2z-styleset?

Has anyone set up a working environment for that?

Is [Tessera](https://github.com/mojodna/tessera) a possible package for such a case?

Comment: I wouldn’t see this as a direct duplicate, since my question is *not only* about hosting vector tiles.

Comment: Reading the [tilelive-vector readme](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive-vector#user-content-vectortm2zuri-callback) it sounds like tilelive might be able to render raster tiles from vector source with a tm2z-live-package. However it doesn’t explicitly mention any rendering, which makes me wonder if something else is needed? Any experiences someone?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  tessera was built for exactly this use-case.  See [tilelive-tmstyle](https://github.com/mojodna/tilelive-tmstyle).

To run, first make sure that your `tm2` `project.yml` file points at a local source (e.g. `mbtiles:///path/to/archive.mbtiles`), then:

`npm install tessera tilelive-tmstyle mbtiles
node_modules/.bin/tessera tmstyle:///path/to/project.tm2`

Comment: Cheers. Still have to try this. Looks very promising!

Comment: The "Points to local source" has been a good gotcha for me, thanks for noting.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that fits to your use case, but I managed to self-host my exported vector tile source with [tilelive](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive.js) and consume the vector tiles with [Mapbox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl/). [See my answer to my related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126550/41744). Styling is done in [Mapbox GL format](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/) not with tm2z.

Comment: Cheers! The Mapbox-GL-JS solution is one possible, and a very interesting solution for my problem. However, compatibility is still an issue at this point. The other way would be to host either Postgis/GeoJSON/Vector Tiles *plus* a rendering server for raster tiles. I still haven’t found a straight-forward way to do this. It could be involving tilelive. Tessera sounds very interesting, I was also hoping someone has any experience using it.

Comment: I'm' confused - maybe mapbox has prevented users from exporting mbtiles since this thread? My only option in mapbox studio is to download a package of the format tm2z

Comment: @mheavers You tried to download a **style** (which is stored in a `.tm2z` file). Instead you should export a **source**. To do that, in menu point `Styles & Sources` (lower left corner) switch to `Sources`. Create or load a source and in menu `Settings` do `Export to MBTiles`.

Comment: @andreas bilger - Thanks - yes I finally figured that out. I think I'm confused now as to how to create a source. Is it not possible to export an existing mapbox source? I do not have any sort of GIS experience, and am not sure where to go for open data.

Comment: @mheavers No, I think it is not possible to export an existing mapbox source. (See [Dan's answer to your other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165407/41744)) The most famous example of open data is probably [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org). [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) provides extracts in `.shp` format that can be used with Mapbox Studio.

Answer (score 0):

[tileserver-gl-light](https://github.com/osm2vectortiles/tileserver-gl-light) is also a recommended server from [osm2vectortiles.org](http://osm2vectortiles.org/)